# Loading a file from the assets folder in Flutter / Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using the `video_player` plugin for Flutter to play a .mp4 file. In the example code, there's a demo for using the `.network()` method to play a file, but in the source code, I'm seeing a `.file()` method for running local content.

I've added my assets directory to the `pubspec.yaml` file, but on iOS, I'm not seeing an easy way to get the file:// path to my video and pass it into the video player.

It looks like this is accomplished with an assetBundle constructor, but I'm not quite sure how to phrase the code. Intuitively, it feels like it should look something like this:

```
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    final video = File('assets/video.mp4'); 

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(video)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guessing you have added something like the following in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

You just need to set the file path as String as follow:

```
_controller = VideoPlayerController.asset(
        'assets/name_of_your_video.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
```

This will work, hope this help.